# Is there any way to load files on the android phone itself?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, epub

I have made a program that scans the phone using recursion to find all epub files located under `"/storage/emulated/0/"`. This which works, and I can load the files found and turn them into an `InputStream`, but I cannot get data from them using [this](http://omtlab.com/api/) API. Using the same code to load epub files from the assets folder works, however.

The code used to turn the file into an InputStream is as follows:

```
//Example location    
bookLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/book.epub"
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

//DOES NOT WORK
InputStream bookStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bookLocation.getBytes("UTF-8"));

//WORKS
InputStream bookStream = assetManager.open("book.epub");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the bookLocation string in a ByteArrayInputStream which creates a stream that gives you the string when read from

What you would really like to do is open a FileInputStream on the filePath in the following way

```
new FileInputStream(bookLocation);
```

Adding that to your code

```
//Example location    
bookLocation = "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/book.epub"
setManager assetManager = getAssets();

//DOES NOT WORK
InputStream bookStream = new FileInputStream(bookLocation);

//WORKS
InputStream bookStream = assetManager.open("book.epub");
```

Comment: I have tried changing this line of code, but the file location is giving a NullPointerException when loading the file, is this perhaps something to do with android preventing apps from loading data from the phone's files? Is there a permission I need to add?